# How to detox a selected image from an expo-image-picker with React native expo

Tags: react-native, expo, e2e-testing, detox, expo-image-picker

I'm new to detox testing, and I'm using detox tests in my project created with React Native Expo. In my registration form, I have a visual selection field where I'm using the expo-image-picker library. While writing detox tests, I managed to open the gallery, but I cannot select a photo from the gallery. Do you have any solution with React Native Expo? Have you encountered this situation before?
"jest": "^29",
"jest-expo": "^48.0.2",
"detox": "^20.9.1",
"expo": "~47.0.14",
"expo-image-picker": "~14.0.2",

Comment: can it work await element(by.id('imagePickerThumbnail')).atIndex(0).tap();

Comment: await element(by.id('select-images')).tap();  this code allows me to open the gallery but I cannot select an image from it.
note : my selected-images id is given to my touchabalbeOpacity @TaronQalashyan